# How to define a symbollic matrix with variables and numbers

Tags: scoping, tensors, concatenation

Newbie here. 
I want to define a (user-defined)function to return symmetric matrices, as I need to define quite a few tensors. I am able to do this using strings. But I need the matrix entries to be variables and not strings.

I have this function now.

```
matF[fn_, size_] := Module[{mat}, 
mat = Table[ToString[fn]<>ToString[j]<>ToString[i],{i, 1,size},{j,1,i}];
MapThread[Join, {mat, Rest /@ Flatten[mat, {{2}, {1}}]}]];
A = matF[A, 3];
```

which returns the following matrix:

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish something similar, where the entries are variables and not strings? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: So instead of `"A11"` you want `A11`? You can use `ToExpression` but `A[1,1]` will be more convenient.

Comment: You could use `Symbol["A" <> "11"]`

Comment: How about: Array[a, {3, 3}] this defines a 3 by 3 array of variables.

Comment: Table[Subscript[A, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] // MatrixForm with subscript